# $X_n$ iid Poisson($\lambda$) with $\lambda>0$. Show that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_n\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}=1$ a.s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_n$ be iid Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda>0$. Show that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_n\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}=1$ with probability 1.

I tried to use the Borell Cantelli's first and second lemmas in a usual way. Distribution is Poisson,hence  calculations got really messy, and I just gave up. Any other way or approach are welcome. I aimed to show $P(\frac{X_n\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}\geq1+\epsilon \mbox{ infinitely often})=0$ and $P(\frac{X_n\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}\geq1-\epsilon \mbox{ infinitely often})=1$ to conclude the result but again I could not continue after some point. Maybe there is an another way

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to be lacking of are good estimates of $P(X_n\geqslant c)$ when $c\to\infty$. Consider that $P(X_n=x+1)=P(X_n=x)\cdot \lambda/(x+1)\leqslant1/2$ if $x\geqslant2\lambda$ hence, for every $c\geqslant2\lambda$,
$$
P(X_n=c)\leqslant P(X_n\geqslant c)\leqslant P(X_n=c)\,\left(1+\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots\right)=2P(X_1=c).
$$
Furthermore, if $c=a\log n/\log\log n$, then $c\log c=a\log n+o(\log n)$ hence the weak form of Stirling's formula $\log c!\sim c\log c$ yields
$$
P(X_n=c)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\lambda^c/c!=\mathrm e^{-c\log c+o(c\log c)}=n^{-a+o(1)},
$$
from which the convergence or divergence of the series $\sum\limits_nP(X_n\geqslant a\log n/\log\log n)$ can be deduced for every $a\ne1$.

Comment: waaoow cool estimate thank you very much!

Comment: @Did I think $P(X_n=x+1)=P(X_n=x)\cdot \lambda/(x+1) $, besides, why is $P(X_n=c)\leqslant P(X_n\geqslant c)\leqslant P(X_n=c)$ true?

Comment: @hil316 Yes  $P(X_n=x+1)=P(X_n=x)\cdot \lambda/(x+1)$. Sorry but where do you see $P(X_n=c)\leqslant P(X_n\geqslant c)\leqslant P(X_n=c)$ in this post?

Comment: @Did Sorry, I meant 
$P(X_n=c)\leqslant P(X_n\geqslant c)\leqslant P(X_n=c)\,\left(1+\frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots\right)$

Comment: @hil316 Better now. The first inequality is obvious, the second comes from $P(X_n\geqslant c)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty P(X_n=c+k)$ and $P(X_n=c+k)\leqslant P(X_n=c)/2^k$ for every $k\geqslant0$.

Comment: @Did Thanks!!!!